# What happens if I put unavailable value in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
function() {
  var id1 = document.getElementById("usrEmailId").value
  var id2 = document.getElementById("usrEmailIdSecondary").value
  var id3 = document.getElementById("emailId").value
}
```

Here, on a HTML page, I have Email Id capture field. There are two pages and one page has only the element `usrEmailId` and `usrEmailIdSecondary` and the other page has the elements `usrEmailId` and `emailI`. So what will happen to variable `id3` in case of first page. What will be stored in it? (NULL, undefined, or  empty)?

Comment: You could have tried it and found out for yourself in less time than it would have taken to post this question

Answer (score 2):

If the element doesn't exist and `getElementById` returns `null`, nothing will get stored at all because trying to access the `.value` property on `null` will throw an exception before.

Answer (score 0):

> *What will be stored in it?*

Short answer: ***Nothing***.

It will throw error as something like "can't get value of null" and code execution stops at this place.

```js
var id1 = document.getElementById("usrEmailId").value; // <---if doesn't exist
console.log('Log it if id1 is null.'); // <---it won't happen
```

Answer (score 0):

An error gets generated on the javascript console. Check this code snippet

```js
function foo() {
  var id1 = document.getElementById("Email1").value
  console.log(id1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="Email">
  <input type="text" id="pwd">
  <button onClick=foo()>Try</button>
</body>
```

Try running the code, you'll find **Cannot read property 'value' of null** appearing on the console whenever a `getElementById("Email1").value` is called as id `Email1` is not present in the page.

Open developer tools/Inspect > Console if console output doesn't appear on screen.

Comment: In the `foo()` function, you have added this line `var id1 = document.getElementById("Email1").value`. 

The id of the input field is `Email`.

Either change `Email1` to `Email` in `foo()` or change the `id` of `input` to `Email1`

Comment: I added `Email1` in `getElementById()` on purpose so that it generates the error on console.